# Convert relational data into JSON Efficiently

Tags: java, mysql, json, jakarta-ee

I have following table `People`

[image]

I want to get relational records and make the JSON Array like following:

```
{ "Person":[
    {"ID":1, 
     "FirstName":"James", 
     "LastName":"Donovan",
     "Child":[
         {"ID":6, "FirstName":"Nikolai", "LastName":"Donovan"}
     ]
    },
    {"ID":2, 
     "FirstName":"Jeffrey", 
     "LastName":"Williams",
     "Child":[
         {"ID":4, "FirstName":"Carol", "LastName":"Williams"},
         {"ID":5, "FirstName":"Sarah", "LastName":"Williams"}
     ]
    },
    .... and so on
  ]
}
```

What I use following approach;
**short summary of below code**: I perform db operation twice in loop and put node into JSON Object is match certain conditions.

```
preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PEOPLE");
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); // ResultSet Object
            
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    Roles = new JSONObject();
    parentNode = new JSONObject();
    childNode = new JSONObject();
            
    while(rs.next()) {
        parentNode.put("ID", rs.getInt("Id"));
        parentNode.put("FirstName", rs.getString("firstname"));
        parentNode.put("LastName", rs.getString("lastname"));

        if(rs.getInt("parent") > 0) { // Equal 0 Mean it has not child
            // Perform again database operation and get record related to parent id
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE parent=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, rs.getInt("id");
            resultSet2 = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            while(resultSet2.next()) {
                childNode.put("ID", rs.getInt("Id"));
                childNode.put("FirstName", rs.getString("firstname"));
                childNode.put("LastName", rs.getString("lastname"));
                
                parentNode.put("Child":childRole); // put child into parent node
            }
       }
    }
}
```

**What I want?**
Performing db select query in loop is *too much expensive* for server side.

Is there any better solution which generate desired JSON of relational data and save me from additional SELECT operations!

I am thankful for your attention!

Comment: Could you put all the `People` in a `Map` using the id as a key? That would save you some resources if the number of records is not too high.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql 5.7 you can you JSON_ARRAY function to create json array. or JSON_OBJECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe use two queries.

1. select blah where parent = 0.
2. select blah where parent != 0 order by parent, id

loop through the results of the second result set and assign them to the parent in the first result set.

use gson (or jackson or whatever json library you prefer) to convert from the object list to the final jason.

brief codelike stuff

```
select the parents (parent = 0).
for each parent row, add the row to a Map<String, Entity> where the key is the parent id.

select the children (parent != 0).
for each child row, get the parent row from the map using the parent id then add them to the parent entity.
```

use the same class for parent and child rows, initialize the child collection to null and create it on the first add of a child.  This way, the child array will be included for parents that have children and not included for parents with no children and for children.

Answer (score -1):

You could issue a single select

```
SELECT p.ID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, c.ID, c.FirstName, c.LastName 
FROM PEOPLE p LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE c ON c.parent = p.ID
ORDER BY p.ID
```

and then loop over the result.
Whenever the parent ID changes (and for the first result row) you build a new current parentNode. Then you read the child data (which may be empty in case the parent has no children) and put it into the child json array of the current parentNode.